# How do I add the equivalent of a :conditions into a scope for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, boolean

I have a model called Contact.

I have added the following method:

```
 def all_completed_events
   # for a given Contact, return all contact_events records that exist and where sugarcrm = false
   return (self.contact_letters + self.contact_postalcards + self.contact_emails + self.contact_voicemails + self.contact_calls)
 end
```

What is missing from these is that I only want self.contact_letters.find(:conditions => "sugarcrm = false") to be the ones selected (sugarcrm is boolean). (obviously this is applied across the other models, contact_letters, contact_emails, etcetera)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also define another named scope and chain it:

```
named_scope nosugar, :conditions => { :sugarcrm => false }

def all_completed_events
  return self.contact_letters.nosugar + self.contact_postalcards.nosugar + ...
end
```

Depending on how your `ContactEvent` model is implemented (is it STI? Are you returning *all* contact_events or just a specific subset of them?) you could get it down to something more like:

```
return self.contact_events.nosugar
```

Comment: ContactEvent isn't a model.  I have separate ContactLetter, ContactPostalcard, etcetera.  Could I lump everything together and then apply the named scope at the end?

Comment: I think you should be able to leverage off your `all_completed_events` method like this: `self.all_completed_events.nosugar`. Not 100% sure though - need a rails console to test it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
(self.contact_letters + self.contact_postalcards + self.contact_emails + self.contact_voicemails + self.contact_calls).select {|record| !record.sugarcrm }
```